# delete a folder from sites-enabled without deleting original folder

Tags: linux

By mistake, i have created a symbolic folder in sites-enabled.
`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.
Now this folder path in site-enabled looks like this **sites-enabled/sites-available**.Now i have to delete this symbolic folder without delete the files of original **sites-available**.If i use this `sudo rm -r sites-available`,then it will empty my **original sites-available**.And `rmdir sites-available` shows not a directory error.

Comment: This question doesn't belong to Stack Overflow

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I think your question has a bit of a wording issue. But if you ran the command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Then what you basically did was create a soft pointer. Which means if you remove `sites-enabled` (which is the soft link) then you will not lose the data in `sites-available`

As for your second point, `sites-enabled` is a soft pointer which means in order to delete it you need to type

```
sudo rm sites-enabled
```

NOTE: Do not put the `-r` argument because it is not a folder.

Comment: Let me know if that explains the question you were asking

Comment: I want to delete sites-available folder's softlink from sites-enabled folder.So why should i use `sudo rm sites-enabled`

Comment: So the command `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` makes a soft link of `sites-available` to `sites-enabled`. 
So if you want to remove `sites-available` you would want to use a hard link to copy the data and then remove `sites-available`. Does that make sense? They have a nice image [here](https://appleinsider.com/articles/07/10/12/road_to_mac_os_x_leopard_time_machine/page/3)